# Add the values from an array of strings together

Tags: java, arrays, string, sum, addition

I have an array of strings with products and values in it.  Laid out like so:

```
ProductA 200
ProductB 50
ProductC 120
ProductD 1100
ProductE 5
```

I need to find the sum of all these numbers.  The best I have been able to do is use this code to find the sum but it is finding the sum of each individual number:

```
for (char c : rdmPrize.replaceAll("\\D", "").toCharArray())
{
    int digit = c - '0';
    sum += digit;
    if (digit % 2 == 0)
    {
        evenSum += digit;
    }
}
```

The output it is giving me in this example would be 17, but I need it to be 1475.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: It gives you 17, because you are adding digits, not numbers.

2 + 5 + 3 + 2 + 5 = 17,

Use Integer.parseInt and then sum numbers.

Comment: Use String.split to split each line into 2 tokens, covert the second token to a number and sum it up.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using `split` on string and get the value at index 1

```
String[] arr = {"ProductA 200","ProductB 50","ProductC 120","ProductD 1100","ProductE 5"};
    int sum =0;
    for(String s : arr) {
        sum+=Integer.parseInt(s.split(" ")[1]);
    }
    System.out.println(sum);   //1475
```

**By using java-8**

```
int total = Arrays.stream(arr).mapToInt(str->Integer.parseInt(str.split(" ")[1])).sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static Integer sumArray( String[] strArr ) {

    Integer sum = 0;
    for ( String numStr : strArr ) {
        sum += Integer.parseInt( numStr );
    }

    return sum;

}
```

You can do it like this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Split strings by spaces
2. parse the value into a number
3. Sum

   ```
   String[] rdmprice = {
           "ProductA 200", 
           "ProductB 50", 
           "ProductC 120", 
           "ProductD 1100", 
           "ProductE 5"
   };

   BigDecimal result = Arrays.stream(rdmprice)
           .map(i -> new BigDecimal(i.split("\\s+")[1]))
           .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);

   System.out.printf("Result: %f", result);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Split every input line by space, you will get an array of space separated strings. Then just parse the desired element to int and add it to the sum.

```
// input[0] = the product name string
// input[1] = the number string

int sum = 0;

for (String[] input : rdmPrize.split(" ")) {
    sum += Integer.parseInt(input[1]);
}

System.out.println(sum);
```